# Dynamic array constraint such that 8'h00 value should come in min 4 elements

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog

I want to randomize dynamic array such that a particular value should come in min `N` elements.

For example, in the following case here are the constraints

Array size should be min 20, max 50

All elements should be either 8'h0a, 8'ha0, 8'hff, 8'h62

All elements should come min 5 times in array.

No 2 same elements should be side by side (a[0] = 8'h0a then a[1] can't be 8'h0a)

Here is the code for that.

```
class trans;
  rand bit [7:0] a [];

  // For 1st Constraint  
  constraint c_size {a.size() inside {[20:50]};}

  // For 2nd Constraint
  constraint c_element {foreach(a[i]) a[i] inside {8'h0a, 8'ha0, 8'hff, 8'h62};}

  // For 3rd Constraint
  constraint c_min {
    // Only valid if 20 entries and all values exact 5 times
    // a.sum() with (int'(item)) == ((10*5)+(160*5)+(255*5)+(98*5));
  }

  // For 4th Constraint
  constraint c_side {foreach (a[i]) (i > 0) -> (a[i] != a[i-1]);}
endclass
```

I am not sure, how to write for `min 5 times`.

Comment: You edited your question by adding more requirements after answers were already posted. That made one of the existing answers invalid. But I wish they would not have deleted their answer to show different approaches to solutions that have less impact on requirement changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to get a count of how many times an expression is true

```
a.sum() with (int'(item==value))
```

It would make it easier if you put the value set into an array. Then you could write

```
int values[]='{8'h0a, 8'ha0, 8'hff, 8'h62};

// For 2nd Constraint
constraint c_element {foreach(a[i]) a[i] inside {values};}
// For 3rd Constraint
constraint c_min {foreach(values[i]
    a.sum() with (int'(item==values[i])) >= 5;
}
```

Comment: It works. Here `item == values[i]` gives bit value and hence the sum of it also is single bit output. That's why we need to cast that bit value to `int`. Can you please confirm my understanding?